# Why do we put 'A' as the look ahead symbol when all have `$`?

Tags: parsing, syntax, compiler-construction, lr-grammar

I am using ***`canonical LR Method`*** to construct the Parsing table.

Consider the grammar :

```
s -> D C A
s -> D a B
a -> C
s -> a A
```

The book I am reading mentions the *first closure state* as :

```
I(0) = [s -> .D C A , $]
       [s -> .D a B , $]
       [a -> .C , A]
       [s -> .a A , $]
```

In the state

```
[a -> .C , A]
```

from where does `A` in the `item` come ? All the items have `$` as a *Look ahead symbol* and third item has `A` .

Please explain this.

Comment: Have you searched for whether it's a known error in the book? Could you give the book title (and edition)?

Comment: Note that for the third item, the symbol _preceding_ the `->` is also different: it's `a` not `s`. Looks like a substitution of the 4th rule in the first.

Comment: @MSalters edited the question . It was a typo

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever http://books.google.co.in/books?id=5QIoFSfhYLMC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false Principles of compiler design

Answer (score 2):

The item:

```
[ a -> · C, A ]
```

Results from the expansion of the item:

```
[ s -> · a A ]
```

in which the nonterminal `a` is followed by the terminal `A`. That means that the reduction of `C` to `a` can occur in a successor state whose context is `s -> a · A`; or, in other words, when the lookahead is `A`.

All of the other items in the state you mention result either from the initial (implicit) item

```
[ s' -> · s $ ]
```

where the nonterminal `s` is followed by the pseudo-terminal `$` (that is, the end-of-input marker), so that their lookaheads are all `$`.

Comment: _"..That means that the reduction of C to a can occur in a successor state whose context is s -> a · A; or, in other words, when the lookahead is A."_ Can you please elaborate. I didn't understand

Comment: @saplingPro: The idea behind LR parsing is that when you're in a state with an item with the dot at the end (e.g. `a -> C ·`), you've got the left hand side (`C`) on the top of the parsing stack, so you can reduce it to the right hand side (`a`). That's a reduction. The lookahead is used to decide whether a reduction is legal. So the item `[ a -> C ·, A ]` means that you can reduce `C` to `a` if the lookahead is `A`. `[ a -> · C, A ]` will transition to `[ a-> C ·, A  ]` after a `C` is shifted. The lookahead is preserved, so it will apply when we get to the reduction state.

Comment: _".. you've got the left hand side (C) on the top of the parsing stack, so you can reduce it to the right hand side (a)."_ In the production, `a->C.` , `C` is on the right hand side and `a` on the left hand. Why do you say the opposite ?

Comment: @saplingPro: because i've always had problems with left and right :) I meant the opposite.